# Facebook graph API how to get "share" reach counts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's suppose that i'll sell food, and i have a facebook page for my restaurant. And then i will ask my customers to share my content. What it want to know is: how many people have seen my content through my customers? because i want to give points for a contest to the customers that help me the most to reach other people with my facebook content. Once i get this list of "the top customers", I want to know their email for some purposes.

I have read the API documentation, but i can't find what i want.

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: i'm using Rails for development.

Comment: Please go read Facebook’s Platform Policies – you are not _allowed_ to reward users for posting your content.

Comment: Understood sir, i have read what you ask for. I edited my answer, the details of my marketing campaign aren't set yet.